# Как в python пронаименовать файл pdf по заданному списку?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

У меня есть файл pdf каждую страницу которого нужно сохранить в отдельном pdf файле с заданием соответствующего наименования файла. Наименования находятся в отдельном списке.

Пока есть такой код, который просто сохраняет в отдельные файлы с наименованием файлов обычной нумерацией:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
 
input_PDF = PdfFileReader(open('my_document.pdf', 'rb'))
 
for i in range(input_PDF.getNumPages()):
    output = PdfFileWriter() 
    new_File_PDF = input_PDF.getPage(i) # 
    output.addPage(new_File_PDF)
    output_Name_File = str(i+1) + ".pdf"
    outputStream = open(output_Name_File, 'wb')
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
```

Как встроить сюда код который будет выбирать наименования из списка просто по порядку?

Comment: `for page, name in zip(input_PDF.getNumPages(), your_names_list): ...`

Comment: Прошу прощения, я новичок в python. Не совсем понял в какую часть кода нужно  вставить Ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу списка наименований в коде, поэтому пусть будет так:

```py
names_list = [f"name{i+1}" for i in range(input_PDF.getNumPages())]
```

Тогда код будет:

```py
# "Сшиваем" номера страниц и соответствующие им имена
for page_num, name in zip(range(input_PDF.getNumPages()), names_list):
    output = PdfFileWriter() 
    new_File_PDF = input_PDF.getPage(page_num)  # Выбираем страницу
    output.addPage(new_File_PDF)
    output_Name_File = f"{name}.pdf"  # Добавляем к имени суффикс .pdf
    outputStream = open(output_Name_File, 'wb')
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
```

---

См. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

---

Учтите, что кол-во страниц должно совпадать с кол-вом имён в списке, иначе цикл закончится на самом коротком из них.

Comment: Благодарю, все работает. Единственное  конструкцию "{name}.pdf" пришлось заменить на name + ".pdf", почему то не работает.